# IDBKeyRange.only and IDBKeyRange.lowerBound together in one query

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I need to convert this sql query to IndexedDB syntax.

```
"SELECT * FROM article WHERE userid=100 AND date_created > '2015-1-15 18:00:00'"
```

I'm thinking about these two solutions.

#### `userid` index

```
var articles = [];
objectStore.index('userid').openCursor(100).onsuccess = function(e){
    var cursor = e.target.result;
    if(cursor){
        var article = cursor.value;
        if(new Date(article.date_created) > new Date('2015-1-15 18:00:00')){
            articles.push(article);
        }
        cursor.continue();
    }esle{
        console.log('done');
    }
};
```

#### `date_created` index

```
var articles = [];
objectStore.index('date_created').openCursor(IDBKeyRange.lowerBound('2015-1-15 18:00:00')).onsuccess = function(e){
    var cursor = e.target.result;
    if(cursor){
        var article = cursor.value;
        if(article.userid === 100){
            articles.push(article);
        }
        cursor.continue();
    }esle{
        console.log('done');
    }
};
```

How can I write a similar query with a compound index on `userid` and `date_created`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm. Try something like using `IDKeyRange.bound`:

```
function queryArticlesByIdDate(id, date, handleArticle) {
  var openRequest = indexedDB.open(...);
  openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
    var db = this.result;
    var articleStore = db.createObjectStore('articles');
    articleStore.createIndex('date-id',['date_created','userid']);
  };
  openRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var db = this.result;
    var articleStore = db.objectStore('articles');
    var dateIdIndex = articleStore.index('date-id');
    var lowerDate = date;
    var upperDate = new Date(date + 1); // or whatever
    var bounds = IDBKeyRange.bound([lowerDate, id], [upperDate, id]);
    var cursorRequest = dateIdIndex.openCursor(bounds);
    cursorRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
      var cursor = this.result;
      if(!cursor) return;
      handleArticle(cursor.value);
      cursor.continue();
    };
  };
}

queryArticlesByIdDate(5, new Date(...), function handler(article) {
  console.dir(article);
});
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it will work only if date string is provided instead of Date object.

Comment: It should work with dates fine. indexedDB accepts dates as one of its four primitive types.  The line (date + 1) is what needs to be changed to make it work. However you do date math in JS, I forget at the moment. Make sure you are storing date objects as properties of your article objects in the object store, and make sure you query using date objects. The data types must match. If strings are working then chances are you are storing dates as strings.